# tableView.reloadData doesn't update UI

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I've read many solutions, they didn't help me

I have table view which is added to my viewcontroller. I dragged it as outlet to controller.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

In viewDidLoad I added

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

I have method to update data in table:

```
private func updateModel() {
    guard let chatUid = UsersManager.sharedInstance.currentChatUID() else { return }

    RealtedUserApi().getRelatedUser("\(chatUid)", successHandler: {  (relatedUsers) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.relatedUsers = relatedUsers
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

which is executed when I do pull-to-refresh, but UI isn't updated

I placed breakepoint in my table cell and there data from server (for instance user's status) are updated, but UI doesn't - user's status in view remains the same in cell's label

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

p.s. relatedUsers is array of object RelatedUser. It's source for my tableView. RelatedUser has status property, which is changed on server and I need to update appropriate label text in cell

Comment: It is possible that your chatUid is empty or your related users is empty. You can try putting print(relatedUsers) to your dispatch async to check if there is something to display

Comment: relatedUser isn't nil. I see rows. I need to update appropriate label text in cell when it changes on server, and relatedUsers is updated, but UI isn't

Comment: What are you returning for `numberOfRows` method?

Comment: in `numberOfRowsInSection` I'm returning `return relatedUsers?.count ?? 0`

Comment: Try this: `if let users = relatedUsers where users.count > 0 {
        self.relatedUsers = users
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }`

Comment: `relatedUsers` is not Optional in block. As I mentioned `self.relatedUsers` is changed. I see changing in my cell, when I placed Breakpoint in my cell: `recentDateMessage.text = relatedUser!.status!`
In `relatedUser!.status!` has already had new data from server, which is assigned to label, but label in View wasn't updeted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was so silly, so it's shame on me:

I commented some part of code in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` block where also was `return cell` and forgot about that. 
But in the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I return `UITableViewCell()`.

Usually In this case App crashes, but in my case It didn't. So I could see rows with data from server, but update didn't work.